# Synchronize Scroll Position of two RichTextBoxes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, richtextbox

In my application's form, I have two `RichTextBox` objects. They will both always have the same number of lines of text. I would like to "synchronize" the vertical scrolling between these two, so that when the user changes the vertical scroll position on one, the other scrolls the same amount. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did this for a small project a while ago, and here's the simplist solution I found.

Create a new control by subclassing RichTextBox:

```
   public class SynchronizedScrollRichTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    {
        public event vScrollEventHandler vScroll;
        public delegate void vScrollEventHandler(System.Windows.Forms.Message message);

        public const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) {
            if (msg.Msg == WM_VSCROLL) {
                if (vScroll != null) {
                    vScroll(msg);
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref msg);
        }

        public void PubWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg) {
            base.WndProc(ref msg);
        }
    }
```

Add the new control to your form and for each control explicitly notify the other instances of the control that its vScroll position has changed.  Somthing like this:

```
private void scrollSyncTxtBox1_vScroll(Message msg) {
    msg.HWnd = scrollSyncTxtBox2.Handle;
    scrollSyncTxtBox2.PubWndProc(ref msg);
}
```

I think this code has problems if all the 'linked' controls don't have the same number of displayable lines.

Comment: This method working fine for scrolling by moving the scrollbar. But the scroll bars are not synchronized when    (1) scrolling with mouse wheel     (2) scrolling by `page down` or `page up` keys     - scrolling by pressing the arrow keys

Comment: @Jay riggs 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'PubWndProc' and no extension method 'PubWndProc' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 23):

Thanks Jay for your answer; after some more searching I also found the method described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/161d1636-aea3-4fee-beb4-52370663d44c/). I'll outline it below for anyone else interested.

---

First, declare the following enums:

```
public enum ScrollBarType : uint {
   SbHorz = 0,
   SbVert = 1,
   SbCtl = 2,
   SbBoth = 3
 }

public enum Message : uint {
   WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115
}

public enum ScrollBarCommands : uint {
   SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4
}
```

Next, add external references to [`GetScrollPos`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getscrollpos) and [`SendMessage`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage).

```
[DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
public extern static int GetScrollPos( IntPtr hWnd, int nBar );

[DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
public extern static int SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
```

Finally, add an event handler for the [`VScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.vscroll.aspx) event of the appropriate [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx):

```
private void myRichTextBox1_VScroll( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   int nPos = GetScrollPos( richTextBox1.Handle, (int)ScrollBarType.SbVert );
   nPos <<= 16;
   uint wParam = (uint)ScrollBarCommands.SB_THUMBPOSITION | (uint)nPos;
   SendMessage( richTextBox2.Handle, (int)Message.WM_VSCROLL, new IntPtr( wParam ), new IntPtr( 0 ) );
}
```

In this case, `richTextBox2`'s vertical scroll position will be synchronized with `richTextBox1`.

Answer (score 6):

[Visual Studio C# 2010 Express, v10.0.30319 on a Windows 7 64bit installation]

I've used Donut's solution posted above, but found a problem when scrolling to the end of RichTextBoxes that contain many lines.

If the result of `GetScrollPos()` is `>0x7FFF` then when `nPos` is shifted, the top bit is set. The creation of the `IntPtr` with the resulting `wParam` variable will then fail with an `OverflowException`. You can easily test this with the following (the second line will fail):

```
    IntPtr ip = new IntPtr(0x7FFF0000);
    IntPtr ip2 = new IntPtr(0x80000000);
```

A version of `SendMessage()` that uses `UIntPtr` would appear to be a solution, but I couldn't get that to work. So, I've use the following:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, UInt32 wParam, UInt32 lParam);
```

This should be good up to `0xffff`, but would fail after that. I've not yet experienced a `>0xffff` result from `GetScrollPos()`, and assume that User32.dll is unlikely to have a 64bit version of `SendCommand()`, but any solutions to that problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int WM_USER = 0x400;

const int EM_GETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 221;

const int EM_SETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 222;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref Point lParam);

private void RichTextBox1_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt;

    SendMessage(RichTextBox1.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);

    SendMessage(RichTextBox2.Handle, EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);
}


private void RichTextBox2_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt;

    SendMessage(RichTextBox1.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);

    SendMessage(RichTextBox2.Handle, EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Jay's subclass approach can be found in Joseph Kingry's answer here: [Synchronizing Multiline Textbox Positions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779949).

Joseph's approach also subclasses but doesn't require a _VScroll event handler. I used that approach to do a 3-way bind between 3 boxes and added WM_HSCROLL.

Answer (score 0):

@Sudhakar MuthuKrishnan's answer needs some fixes, but works. Thanks!

First GetScrollPos which rised event and then set scroll position for others.

```
private void RichTextBox1_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = new Point();

    SendMessage(RichTextBox1.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);

    SendMessage(RichTextBox2.Handle, EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);
}


private void RichTextBox2_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = new Point();

    SendMessage(RichTextBox2.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);

    SendMessage(RichTextBox1.Handle, EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, ref pt);
}
```