# Powershell: Sync Scrolling of two Richtextboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, event-handling, richtextbox

I want to sync the scrolling of two `Winforms` Richtextboxes. When RTB2 gets scolled, RTB1 needs to be exactly aligned all the time. 
I tried to convert this c#-Code here [LINK (second answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827323/c-synchronize-scroll-position-of-two-richtextboxes), but failed so far. So I need help.
Right now it produces multiple errors:

```
Type [ScrollBarCommands] was not found...
Type [ScrollBarType] was not found....
Type [Message] was not found...
Also "illegal conversions" and so on.
```

This is an example script:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.size  = "400,400"
$rtb1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$rtb1.size  = "190,350"
$rtb1.location = "200,1"
$rtb1.text = (1..300 | out-string)
$form.controls.add($rtb1)
$rtb2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$rtb2.size  = "190,350"
$rtb2.location = "1,1"
$rtb2.text = (1..300 | out-string)
$rtb2.scrollbars = "none"
$form.controls.add($rtb2)

$code = @'
public enum ScrollBarType : uint {
   SbHorz = 0,
   SbVert = 1,
   SbCtl = 2,
   SbBoth = 3
 }
public enum Message : uint {
   WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115
}
public enum ScrollBarCommands : uint {
   SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4
}
[DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
public extern static int GetScrollPos( IntPtr hWnd, int nBar );
[DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
public extern static int SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
'@
Add-Type -Name WinUtils -MemberDefinition $code -Namespace User32

$rtb1.add_VScroll({ 
   [uint32]$nPos = [User32.WinUtils]::GetScrollPos( $rtb1.Handle, [ScrollBarType]::SbVert )
   [uint32]$npos = $nPos -shl 16
   [uint32]$wParam = [ScrollBarCommands]::SB_THUMBPOSITION -bor $nPos
   [User32.WinUtils]::SendMessage( $rtb2.Handle, [Message]::WM_VSCROLL, $wParam , [ref]0)
})

$form.showdialog()
```

**Editors, please note: It's not a duplicate, this is about **Powershell**. :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrollBarType`, `ScrollBarCommands`, and `Message` are members of `User32.WinUtils` namespace. Also, `ptr` should be `System.IntPtr`.

**EDIT:**
To scroll `$rtb2` while dragging the scrollbar (and not just when mouse is released), you have to use `GetScrollInfo`

**EDIT 2:**
Fixed arrow scroll buttons not working

**EDIT 3:**
Fixed other bugs. Restructured code.

```
$typeDef = @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public enum ScrollBarType : uint {
    SbHorz = 0,
    SbVert = 1,
    SbCtl  = 2,
    SbBoth = 3
}

public enum Message : uint {
    WmVScroll = 0x0115
}

public enum ScrollBarCommands : uint {
    ThumbPosition = 4,
    ThumbTrack    = 5
}

[Flags()]
public enum ScrollBarInfo : uint {
    Range           = 0x0001,
    Page            = 0x0002,
    Pos             = 0x0004,
    DisableNoScroll = 0x0008,
    TrackPos        = 0x0010,

    All = ( Range | Page | Pos | TrackPos )
}

public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox {
    public Control Buddy { get; set; }

    public bool ThumbTrack = false;

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    public struct ScrollInfo {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public int nMin;
        public int nMax;
        public uint nPage;
        public int nPos;
        public int nTrackPos;
    };

    [DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
    public extern static int SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
    [DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
    public extern static int GetScrollInfo( IntPtr hWnd, int fnBar, ref ScrollInfo lpsi );

    public void CustomVScroll() {
        int nPos;

        ScrollInfo scrollInfo = new ScrollInfo();
        scrollInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf( scrollInfo );

        if (ThumbTrack) {
            scrollInfo.fMask = (uint)ScrollBarInfo.TrackPos;
            GetScrollInfo( this.Handle, (int)ScrollBarType.SbVert, ref scrollInfo );
            nPos = scrollInfo.nTrackPos;
        } else {
            scrollInfo.fMask = (uint)ScrollBarInfo.Pos;
            GetScrollInfo( this.Handle, (int)ScrollBarType.SbVert, ref scrollInfo );
            nPos = scrollInfo.nPos;
        }

        nPos <<= 16;
        uint wParam = (uint)ScrollBarCommands.ThumbPosition | (uint)nPos;
        SendMessage( Buddy.Handle, (int)Message.WmVScroll, new IntPtr( wParam ), new IntPtr( 0 ) );
    }

    protected override void WndProc( ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m ) {
        if ( m.Msg == (int)Message.WmVScroll ) {
            if ( ( m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFF ) == (int)ScrollBarCommands.ThumbTrack ) {
                ThumbTrack = true;
            } else {
                ThumbTrack = false;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc( ref m );
    }
}
"@

$assemblies = ("System.Windows.Forms", "System.Runtime.InteropServices")

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $typeDef -Language CSharp

### Form

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = "400,400"

### Rich text box 1 (Synchronized - master)

$rtb1 = New-Object CustomRichTextBox

$rtb1.Size = "190,350"
$rtb1.Location = "200,1"
$rtb1.Text = (1..300 | Out-String)

$form.Controls.Add($rtb1)

### Rich text box 2 (Synchronized - slave)

$rtb2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

$rtb2.Size = "190,350"
$rtb2.Location = "1,1"
$rtb2.Text = (1..300 | Out-String)
$rtb2.ScrollBars = "none"

$form.Controls.Add($rtb2)

### Synchronization setup

$rtb1.Buddy = $rtb2

$rtb1.Add_VScroll({
    $this.CustomVScroll()
})

### Run

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Excellent thanks!, Just one more question: right now the RTB1 gets only scolled when the user is done scrolling (mouse button release), is there any way to tweak that so that RTB1 gets scrolled while the user is still scrolling?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Just try it, and you see what I mean :) When you scroll the right box, the left one gets only scrolled when you release the scroll-bar and stop scrolling. This is fine, but ideally the would both scroll simultaneously.  I jut saw: this only occurs if you scoll woth the mouse and the scroll-bar.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, as I was using scrollwheel, which works alright. Let me see if I can get that working too..

Comment: For some reason, `[User32.WinUtils]::GetScrollPos( $rtb1.Handle, [User32.WinUtils+ScrollBarType]::SbVert )` is not updating while dragging the scroll bar.

Comment: So no chance? :)

Comment: I can't seem to find anything yet. I'll keep searching.

Comment: You are using `SB_THUMBPOSITION`, and it should be `SB_THUMBTRACK`. " This message is sent repeatedly until the user releases the mouse button." But setting it doesn't work.

Comment: There is also `GetScrollInfo`, which should fit this case. Just have to get it working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166124/discussion-between-bozo-stojkovic-and-moss).

Comment: I nearly missed this because when you edit, I dont get a notification. Anyway, this is some excellent coding, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I thought you will get notified by the room.. Glad I helped. It was a nice exercise.

Comment: Hey :) One odd thing though: If you hold the scrollbar and drag up, it  doesent stop scolling the other RTB at line one, but jumps to the point where you started. Difficult to explain. :) Its not a biggy, but is there an easy way to simply stop scolling up when line 1 is reached?

Comment: Could you proceed any discussion in the chatroom, please? Thanks.