# How to move two scrollbars simultaneously

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 `DataGridViews`. Assume that they have always the same amount of rows with the same height. Whenever I move the `ScrollBar` on one of them (both with the `MouseWheel` and the `ScrollBar`), I'd like to move the other one simultaneously (I only want to do this on the vertical `ScrollBars`). How can I achive this?

Comment: Why are they not just one datagridview then?

Comment: Syncronize their `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` properties

Comment: @Caius Jard it was a specific request of the client. What do you mean by syncronizing their properties?

Comment: DGV has a FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property that either tells you or allows you to set which row is displayed first.. If you scroll one DGV (so it's eg now showing row 10 as its first row) you can get which index is first (e.g. 10) and set the other DGV so it's showing the same first row (eg 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Caius Jard is saying to you to do is:

First, create two DataGridView, then on the `Scroll` event sync the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`.

```
dataGridView1.Scroll += DataGridView1OnScroll;

private void DataGridView1OnScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs scrollEventArgs) {
    dataGridView2.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
}
```

**Observation**

I tried to use `WndProc` to sync two DataGrids, [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1827608/5734097), but it did not work… Well, it worked with the mouse wheel, but not by dragging the scrollbar.